# Calculating Binormal Vector

Tags: vector, shader

Is Binormal vector a cross product of normalized tangent vector and normalized normal vector or vice versa?

```
Binormal_vector = cross(normalize(tangent_vector), normalize(normal_vector))
```

or

```
Binormal_vector = cross(normalize(normal_vector), normalize(tangent_vector))
```

Many resources like this (http://mathonline.wikidot.com/method-for-calculating-unit-normal-and-unit-binormal-vectors) define Binormal vector as

```
B = T X N
```

But in most of the shader codes Binormal vector is defined as

```
Binormal_vector = cross(normalize(normal_vector), normalize(tangent_vector)) * handedness
```

i.e.

```
B = N X T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an [Right-Handed Coordinate System](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandedCoordinateSystem.html) (see further [Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule))

[image: right handed TBN]

the Binormal Vector is calcualted by:

```
B = N x T
```

while in an [Left-Handed Coordinate System](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Left-HandedCoordinateSystem.html)

[image: left handed TBN]

the Binormal Vector is calcualted by:

```
B = T x N
```

In OpenGL is commonly used a [Right-Handed Coordinate System](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandedCoordinateSystem.html), but this depends on the specification and definitions which are chosen by the user.

Further if a system is mirrored it changes from one system to the other. This may occur if a texture is mirrored or looked at from the backface.
Note in your above code this is compensated by `handedness`, which is the "sign" of the binormal vector and either 1.0 or -1.0.

```
Binormal_vector = cross(normalize(normal_vector), normalize(tangent_vector)) * handedness
```